# Zend_Form Display Groups Problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, fieldset

Here is a short snippet from my class extending Zend_Form:

```
$this->addElements(array(
    $inputField1,
    $inputField2,
    $inputField3,
    $submitButton
));

$this->addDisplayGroup(array('inputField1',
                             'inputField2',
                             'inputField3',
                             'submitButton'),
                       'fieldset1',
                       array('legend' => 'Lorem Ipsum'));
```

The problem is when I print the form, it prints only the submit button, the fieldset with input fields (those are ordinary Zend_Form_Element_Text elements) isn't there.

EDIT: If I remove the $this->addDisplayGroup() (or comment it), the text elements are displayed without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you aren't using the getDisplayGroup() in your controller or later on in the form init() method